# Finding points on the circumference of an arc

Tags: trigonometry, circles

Sorry, it may be a simple task but it has been 30 years since I finished high school. :)

I have an initial course to a center of a circle (x0=100 and y0=100), which is, say, 150 degrees. The radius of the circle is 10. I also have an angle at which I draw an arc around the circumference of the circle, 30 degrees.

I need to find four things:
1) Left top corner of the bounding square for the circle. This is easy. x3=90 and x4=90.
2) First point of the original line entering the arc (x1 and y1).
3) Second point of the final line leaving the arc (x2 and y2).
4) Angle between right corner of the circle and the first point of the original line entering the arc (x1 and y1).

[image]

Could someone please remind of trigonometry?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Since this is needed for Java code, these are some of the specific conditions:

1) Original coordinates (0,0) are located in the top left corner of the screen;

2) Original angle (0º) is at the rightmost point of the circle.

3) Positive is a counterclockwise rotation starting at 0º.

Comment: Do you need an exact answer or even algebraic working? If you only need the numbers I suggest using GeoGebra. It really is very useful for this type of problem and saves a lot of calculation.

Comment: Thank you, Karn. I need universal formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
(x_1, y_1) = (100 + 10 \cos 150^\circ, 100 - 10 \sin 150^\circ)
$$
because $(x_1, y_1)$ is 150 degrees around from the rightmost point of the circle, and the circle-center is at $(100, 100)$, and the radius is 10, and $y$ increases down instead of up, which makes for the "-" in the second term.

$$
(x_2, y_2) = (100 + 10 \cos 180^\circ, 100 - 10 \sin 180^\circ)
$$

because that point is $30$ degrees further around from a point at angle 150 degrees.

The angle you're looking at (the red arc) is $150^\circ$. (That also means that your picture is wrong, because the black arrow in the lower left should be headed about west-north-west, not west-south-west. )

Comment: Thanks a lot, John. The picture is wrong, I agree. It was just an example. Also, should it be (100-xxxx), since the coordinates start from the top left corner of the screen? Cheers.

Comment: John. Also, 1) The first point is at 150 degrees. Does your second formula match the first point and not vice versa? 2) Should the second point be at (150+30=180 degrees) instead? 3) Should it be (100-xxxx), since the coordinates start from the top left corner of the screen? Cheers.

Comment: `When you say the first point is at 150 degrees, I understood you to say "the first ray has a course of 150"; I assumed that this is was in the standard "north 0, 360, East = 90, South = 180" coordinate system, (i.e., degrees measured clockwise from north", because that's what "heading" usually means, at least in navigational terms. The standard "math" angle heading is measured counterclockwise from the eastmost point of the circle, and that's the one I was using in my answer. Why do you say that coordinates start from the top left of the screen in your comment? The question doesn't say that!

Comment: John. I am sorry to have missed some details. I have added them in the question. How would this affect the formulas. As they are now, the drawn lines in my program are not correct.

Comment: Fixed to reflect your added details. By the way, the "course" of the initial arrow is in direction $-30$, not $150$, at least if it's anything like what you've drawn. The direction from the circle center *toward* the source of the arrow is $150$ degrees around from the right-most point of the circle.